# Error when building documentation of Postgres

Tags: postgresql, documentation, mac-os-x

I am trying to build the documentation of Postgres on OSX

After getting the source, installing node and jade, I do:

```
cd /doc/src/sgml
make html
```

This results in the error:

```
   fs.js:684
  return binding.lstat(pathModule._makeLong(path));

         ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/thomas/Source/postgres/doc/src/sgml/-p'
    at Object.fs.lstatSync (fs.js:684:18)
    at Object.realpathSync (fs.js:1272:21)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/node_modules/monocle/monocle.js:41:26
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.watchFiles (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/node_modules/monocle/monocle.js:39:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/bin/jade.js:98:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

The directory that the make script is expecting to find looks really odd. What am I doing wrong?

My `jade --version` is 1.3.1.

Comment: It'd help if you showed the Makefile line / make target it failed at. Also, `jade --version` please.

Answer (score 1):

> `Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/thomas/Source/postgres/doc/src/sgml/-p'`

I'd say you have some ancient version of one of the required tools, and it's seeing the `-p` command-line switch as a regular path argument instead.